# pentaho kettle transformation/step log not working on scheduler

Tags: transformation, scheduler, pentaho, kettle

I have a kettle job with two transformations.
 
Trans1: runs and the result is logged into kettle transformation & step log tables.
 
Trans2: checks the step log table for result of Trans1 and success if Trans1 run without error.

the job works fine if i call it manually, but when i schedule it the transformation and step logs got delayed and Trans2 fails.
I am not sure what causes the log delay.